# Trying to understand CreateDefaultBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, identityserver4

I am a newbie to writing C# Api, and am looking at IdentityServer4 QuickStart1
I see that the QuickstartIdentityServer module has

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace QuickstartIdentityServer
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "IdentityServer";

            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

And the API has

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace Api
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "API";

            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

I am having problems understanding what BuildWebHost actually does and why I need it to be running in 2 separate processes before I can use my client process to connect to the API

I see that BuildWebHost contains

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder
```

Looking at  Microsoft.AspNetCore (from metadata)  I see that it is a static class that contains the declaration of a method

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateDefaultBuilder(string[] args);
```

So the actual code for the method must be in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Dll

Why does it need to run both in IdentityServer4 and the Api ?

Comment: `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()` is located in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` assembly.  It has nothing to do with dependency injection...it's a stock standard static method.

Comment: Thanks @Brad I corrected the question.

Comment: No, it doesn't show the body. but with the latest Visual Studio (15.7 or 15.8 preview), it will try to decompile the target library using ILSpy to show the contents. Though its not 1:1 as the original source, but usually good enough to give you an idea about what happens htere

Comment: Technically it doesn't have to.  That's just how the quickstart is structured.  You could _merge_ the projects to host the API controllers in the IdentityServer4 project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

That is the default bit of code that is necessary to get an ASP.NET Core application up and running. What this basically does is create a web host with the usual defaults, configures the Startup class and then builds the web host. The web host is then the thing that actually serves your web application.

You can take a look [at the implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L152) of `CreateDefaultBuilder` but judging by the actual question you have, this won’t help you very much.

> Why does it need to run both in IdentityServer4 and the Api?

The thing the Identity Server examples do here is have the Identity Server and the API on *separate servers*. This is technically not necessary, and you *could* host them both within the same application. However, in practice it is a lot more likely that you deploy the Identity Server once in some central location, and then you maybe have multiple other servers—APIs, clients, whatever—that use the server as an external authentication provider.

So they are creating separate web hosts because they are separate web applications. They are separate web applications created in separate .NET projects.

If you read the [quickstart tutorial](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) closely, you will notice that they actually do create separate projects for this. And separate ASP.NET Core projects means separate web applications which are each hosted individually.